# How can I access the "name" and "ObjectId" from this array of Objects? (Mongoose, MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to access the name property. I tried doing the following but it returned `undefined`:

```js
Category.find()
    .select("-_id")
    .select("-__v")
    .then((categories) => {
      let creator = req.userId;
      console.log(categories.name) //undefined
      if (categories.creator === creator && categories.name === categoryName) {
        note
          .save()
```

this is `console.log(categories)` :

```js
[
  { name: 'test11', creator: new ObjectId("6359766eaf27f731e789f061") },
  { name: 'test11', creator: new ObjectId("6359766eaf27f731e789f061") },
  { name: 'categ1', creator: new ObjectId("635a316453d25ea50a3a4c5c") },
  { name: 'categ1', creator: new ObjectId("635a316453d25ea50a3a4c5c") },
  { name: 'categ1', creator: new ObjectId("635a316453d25ea50a3a4c5c") },
  { name: 'categ1', creator: new ObjectId("635a316453d25ea50a3a4c5c") },
  { name: 'categ1', creator: new ObjectId("635a316453d25ea50a3a4c5c") },
  {
    name: 'newCategName',
    creator: new ObjectId("635a316453d25ea50a3a4c5c")
  }
]
```

I want to check that if the current signed in user's ID and the document name match an exact pair in the Category schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since categories returned is a list of objects and not a single object. You can use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to filter your condition.

```js
var categories = [
  { name: "test11", creator: new ObjectId("6359766eaf27f731e789f061") },
  { name: "test11", creator: new ObjectId("6359766eaf27f731e789f061") },
  { name: "categ1", creator: new ObjectId("635a316453d25ea50a3a4c5c") },
  { name: "categ1", creator: new ObjectId("635a316453d25ea50a3a4c5c") },
  { name: "categ1", creator: new ObjectId("635a316453d25ea50a3a4c5c") },
  { name: "categ1", creator: new ObjectId("635a316453d25ea50a3a4c5c") },
  { name: "categ1", creator: new ObjectId("635a316453d25ea50a3a4c5c") },
  {
    name: "newCategName",
    creator: new ObjectId("635a316453d25ea50a3a4c5c"),
  },
];

const found = categories.find(
  (doc) => doc.creator === creator && doc.name === categoryName
);

if (found) {
  // rest of the code
}
```

Although a better and efficient approach based on the use case could be to directly use the filter condition in the query itself rather than fetching all categories and then filtering.

```js
const creator = req.userId;
const categoryName = "ABC";
const result = await Category.findOne(
  { creator: creator, name: categoryName },
  "-_id -__v"
).exec();

if (result) {
  // rest fo the code
}
```

Used [`findOne()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) and second param projection to get the matching category.

Answer (score 1):

Categories here is an array of objects, which contain name and ObjectId.

So just loop over the array and get what you want.
In the code I see you do this:

```
console.log(categories.name)
```

Try:

```
console.log(categories[0].name)
```